# Is it possible to see the engagement the contact/lead in Individual Email Result like the button clicked in the email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sales-cloud

We had a Sales Cloud integrated to Marketing Cloud and we want to see in Individual Email Result the areas which the contacts or leads engaged in in an email especially in dynamic content.

Comment: You're looking for Impression Region data. Unfortunately it's not pushed back to Sales Cloud, but is available in impression region reports and through tracking extracts.